# Drag and Drop functionality in RichTextField

Tags: wagtail, richtextediting

Is it possible to implement such a function(dragAndDrop) in a Wagtail? Something similar is already done in Froala WYSIWYG editor

[image]

It's really tiring, adding photos if you have more than 100 of them.
[I've already seen this solution, but it also means a lot of button presses.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wagtail/iXh5aQYwSkk/CCU3pVsEBAAJ)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can drag and drop multiple images into the Image manager:

[image: wagtail image uploader]

and then select them quickly using search or browse from the Rich Text image selector:

[image: wagtail image chooser]

We prefer this approach because it encourages editors to provide good metadata (especially alt text) for their images.